# mongomapper rails 3 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid, mongomapper

I am using mongomapper throughotu my rails 3 app but am using authlogic and active record for authentication and storing users.

I am now changing this to devise and mongomapper like the rest of my app.

I know devise seems to now support mongoid but i don't want to mix mongid and mongomapper and now that mongomapper uses active modle it should work with devise.

I have seen some forks but they don't seem active since earlier this year.

What is the recommended way to use devise with MM now ?   Isnt there just a orp adapter i now ?   or do i use a fork of devise ?

cheers
Rick

Comment: are you still using MM? we're using MM, but seriously thinking about switching to mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Kristian Mandrup's MM-Devise adapter: https://github.com/kristianmandrup/mm-devise

Hopefully it still works with more recent versions of Devise/MM.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the mm-Devise adapter described above and it works great...  You have to do some tweaking to get it to work as the documentation seemed a little out of date when used with ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.

Comment: I just got notice that you posted this question, are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: Not really..  moved on to something else now. Thanks for checking!

Comment: I could use your tweaks. mm-devise + mongo yields not so much info online.

Comment: Leon let me know if you are still in need of them and any specific questions you have and I might be able to help you.